# Website rebuilt, google analytics only getting old URLs

Tags: google-analytics

I recreated my website on a new server and create a brand new Google Analytics property for it. It's been running for a week, the problem is literally all my pageviews recorded are pointing to old website's URLs, which of course don't exist. I understand that people kind of saved old URLs and directly visiting them, but how is it possible that 100% of my pageview URLs are old? Me and my colleagues were constantly visiting the new site during the last week, how come these pageviews are never recorded?

As you can see in the screenshot, all of my pageviews return a 404 page, because the URLs don't exist on the new website.
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't suggest putting the GA tracking code on your 404 Not Found page.  GA does a much better reporting when you only feed it good URLs.

Comment: When you rebuild your website, you should redirect the old URLs to the new ones.   It isn't good user experience or good for SEO to change your URLs without mapping them to their new locations.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question without further information.  What is the source of your visitors?  Can you look at the "acquisition" section and include that info?  If everybody is coming in through search engines, they are likely coming to deep pages mainly.

Comment: Have you verified that your page titles on your new site aren't all "Page not Found"?